# Why is west side wing at higher potential?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

> A Boeing 747 with a wingspan of 64.4 m is flying in this area due north at 275 m/s. The earth's magnetic field at the plane’s location has a magnitude of 52.5 µT. Although it points north, it is deflected down 64.5° below the horizontal.
> a. Determine the induced emf across the plane's wings.
> b. Which wing tip is at the higher potential, the one on the west side of the plane or the one one the east side of the plane?  Explain how you arrived at your answer.  (ans: west side)

Using fleming's right hand rule, if the plane is heading north, direction of magnetic field is down, direction of the current should be from east wing to west wing and that should make east wing at higher potential since current flows from high potential to low potential. But the answer key suggests otherwise. How can the west wing have higher potential if current flows towards it?

Answer (score 0):

> using fleming's right hand rule, if the plane is heading north, direction of magnetic field is down, direction of the current should be from east wing to west wing

Yes, the magnetic force will point towards the west for a *positive* charge and to the east for a *negative* charge

> and that should make east wing at higher potential since current flows from high potential to low potential.

If you have accumulation of positive charge at the west end and negative charge at the east, then the west end is at the higher potential.

You are getting mixed up with the current flow from the induced EMF vs from an electrostatic field. You can think of the wings moving in the magnetic field kind of like the inside of a battery, where positive charges move from low to high potential; that's the idea behind an EMF.